# Doublet impulse force harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

I initially asked this on a math forum, but I see now that physics was a better choice. I'm considering an at-rest simple harmonic oscillator (m,k) and want to model the force by a doublet (derivative of dirac delta) at t=0.
$$f = \delta'(t)$$
I've already considered the case for a dirac delta, and I'm supposing that a Green's function method will suffice. As normal,
$$G = \frac{1}{mw}\sin (w(t-t'))$$
For a dirac delta $f=\delta(t)$, the solution is clearly just $f=\frac{1}{mw}\sin(wt)$ by convolution. I believe this therefore imposes the condition that $\dot x(0^+) = 1/mw$, though I'm not entirely certain.

For doublet, applying integration by parts, I get that $f = \frac{1}{M}\cos(wt)$. However, this clearly cannot be true. In my mind, the idea of $\delta'(t)$ is a spike and a negative spike, meaning the behavior directly after must be $x=0$, since impulses cancel. However, this result clearly conflicts with that. I don't think I have the freedom to impose a coefficient of zero, so I don't know how to proceed.

In short, for a dirac delta and a doublet forcing function, what initial conditions are imposed and how does my $f = \cos$ align with my intuition for a doublet (that it remains at rest)?